# Possible to shorten a 17 digit decimal using math

Tags: math

Im using a database that can only accept float/doubles of 17 decimal precision. Is it possible to take a number ex 10.123456789012345678 which has 20 digits and shorten it down without losing any data? Its been a while since ive done this kind of math but exponents come to mind just not sure how to apply here without losing digits

Comment: Have you considered multiplying by 1000 for example?

Comment: wouldnt that just move the decimal place? I need to shorten total numbers but i can include e in the number.

Comment: I couldn't think of any way except for separating the number into two parts and storing them separately

Comment: @Ponzi314 By "shorten" I assume you mean shortening the textual representation? A **full-precision** textual representation of an arbitrary `double` typically requires a C++ `printf()` format like `% 23.16e`.  Switching to hexadecimal floating-point format (e.g. `% 23.13a`) won't save characters in the general case. Are there inherent range or accuracy restrictions on the input data?